# Large image gallery preview. Multiple div toggle with two arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a large image preview . I have created a basic html template, but have no Idea how accomplish this task.

Here is a link to something I would like. [Gallery Artwork Preview](http://ropac.net/selected_works/jules-de-balincourt)

Here is everything I have. 
P.S I purposely put everything in one file.

```
<?php
$colors =array("red","green","orange","blue");
$colorLen = count($colors);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="stylesheets/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .myDiv{float:left; width:150px; height:150px; margin:10px;}
  .myDiv img{width:100%; height: 100%;}
  .myDiv p{text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
  .hidden{display: none;}
  .myLink{margin:20px;}
  #prev{float: left;}
  #next{float: right;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#0").removeClass("hidden"); //set the first div to be visible
});
</script>

</head>
<body style="display:inline-block; width:auto;">

<a id="prev" class="myLink" href="#">Prev</a>

<?php //Cycle through the colors and create a div with image and title tag
$i =0;
while ($i != $colorLen) { 
    echo '<div id="'.$i.'" class="myDiv hidden" style="background-color:'.$colors[$i].';">
        <img src="#" alt="'.$colors[$i].'"/><p>'.ucfirst($colors[$i]).'</p>
         </div>';
    $i++;
}
?>

<a id="next" class="myLink" href="#">Next</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
var numItems =$('.myDiv').length; //Get the number of elements on the page
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: What have you tried? For someone with no idea how to achieve their objective, you seem to have written a lot of code! What's wrong with the code you've written? You're asking for help to solve a problem, it would help if you described the problem.

Comment: @nurdglaw I can read javascript and jQuery but I dont have enough grasp  of those languages to accomplish this task. I have googled A lot and could not find a working solution to what seems like pretty generic thing.    The solutions I found are usually sliders that do not incorporate separate text blocks. I hope this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the solution. The main changes are 
1. Initialized my divs as hidden by default in css part.
2. Removed hidden class from css and added selected instead. (easier to read and understand) 
3. Last but not least added the code. Keep in mind that the slider does not stop it loops through all the elements.

```
<?php
$colors =array("red","green","orange","blue","black");
$colorLen = count($colors);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="stylesheets/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .myDiv{float:left; width:150px; height:150px; margin:10px; display: none;}
  .myDiv img{width:100%; height: 100%;}
  .myDiv p{text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
  .selected{display: block;}
  .myLink{margin:20px;}
  #prev{float: left;}
  #next{float: right;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>
<body style="display:inline-block; width:auto;">

<a id="prev" class="myLink" href="#">Prev</a>

<?php
$i =0;
while ($i != $colorLen) {
    echo '<div class="myDiv" style="background-color:'.$colors[$i].';">
        <img src="#" alt="'.$colors[$i].'"/><p>'.ucfirst($colors[$i]).'</p>
         </div>';
    $i++;
}
?>

<a id="next" class="myLink" href="#">Next</a>


<script type="text/javascript">

if(!$('.myDiv').first().hasClass('selected')){ //Set the first div to be visible
  $('.myDiv').first().addClass('selected');
}

var $first = $('.myDiv:first', 'body'),
    $last = $('.myDiv:last', 'body');

$("#next").click(function () {

    var $next,
        $selected = $(".selected");
    // get the selected item
    // If next div is empty , get the first
    $next = $selected.next('div').length ? $selected.next('div') : $first;
    $selected.removeClass("selected").fadeOut('fast');
    $next.addClass('selected').fadeIn('fast');
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    var $prev,
        $selected = $(".selected");
    // get the selected item
    // If prev div is empty , get the last
    $prev = $selected.prev('div').length ? $selected.prev('div') : $last;
    $selected.removeClass("selected").fadeOut('slow');
    $prev.addClass('selected').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```